# Value interpolation issue with Python SQLite3 library

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have an odd problem with an SQL query and I'm finding it difficult to debug unfortunately.

I have a query that inserts a user into a db, if I run this debug statement I get the values returned from the form.

```python
app.logger.debug(f'''{request.form.get("firstName").capitalize()}, {request.form.get("lastName").capitalize()}, {request.form.get("userName").lower()}, {request.form.get("inputEmail").lower()}, {generate_password_hash(request.form.get("inputPassword"), method="sha256")}''')
```

which are as follows

```
DEBUG: David, Taylor, taylord, dave@imagetaylor.com, sha256$xXfFJg6EKm9V7O5D$f8eadba22c3ad99c4133ac9ae4d2d25dfe9665b70df04d51417d1caec708ab4c
```

if I then plug those into the SQL query everythings works

```python
dbexe("INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,username,email,hash) VALUES('David','Taylor','taylord','dave@imagetaylor.com','sha256$04meQSacFSYL12aq$b17d53e8a3de54e0dcf66c11cf36858f551b9b72a771b18c9b8f3bf24599f8b2')")
```

However when I use safe interpolation through the sqlite3 library it fauls and I'm having trouble finding a way to see the issue.

```python
dbexe("INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,username,email,hash) VALUES('?','?','?','?','?')", request.form.get("firstName").capitalize(), request.form.get("lastName").capitalize(), request.form.get("userName").lower(), request.form.get("inputEmail").lower(), generate_password_hash(request.form.get("inputPassword"), method="sha256"))
```

The dbexec function is as follows.

```python
def dbexe(query):
    try:
        retval = []
        db = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
        db.row_factory = dict_factory
        for row in db.execute(query):
            retval.append(row)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
    except:
        return "Failed"
    return retval
```

Comment: There's no safe interpolation. Your code is using a query with parameters, not interpolation of any kind. `?` is a parameter, not a format placeholder and shouldn't be quoted. Use `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)` instead of `VALUES('?','?','?','?','?')`.

There's no safe interpolation. The code is using a query with parameters, not string interpolation of any kind. `?` is a parameter, not a format placeholder and shouldn't be quoted. The parameter *values* are included in the query itself. They're sent as separate, strongly-typed values to the database alongside the query. The database then compiles the query into a parameterized execution plan which gets executed using those values.

This way you can send numbers, dates, or strings containing anything to the server without worrying about formats or injection risks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dbexe` function doesn't accept the additional arguments, so you'll certainly get a `TypeError`.

If you want to retain the `dbexe(sql, a, b, c)` calling convention and `db.execute()` would generally require the placeheld arguments as a single tuple, you can do

```
def dbexe(query, *args):
   ...
   for row in db.execute(query, args):
      ...
```

I would recommend getting rid of the `try: except:` though, since as it is, you can *never* know what actually went wrong, and to open the database connection in a `with` block:

```
def dbexe(query, *args):
    with sqlite3.connect("main.db") as db:
        db.row_factory = dict_factory
        retval = list(db.execute(query, args))
        db.commit()
    return retval
```

Furthermore, as noted in the comments, you do not want to quote the question marks:

```
dbexe(
    "INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,username,email,hash) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    request.form.get("firstName").capitalize(),
    request.form.get("lastName").capitalize(),
    request.form.get("userName").lower(),
    request.form.get("inputEmail").lower(),
    generate_password_hash(request.form.get("inputPassword"), method="sha256"),
)
```

Comment: The query is wrong to begin with. Instead of using parameter placeholders, `?`, it uses strings with question marks, `'?'`. That's why the arguments don't match

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah yeah, I didn't notice that. Added an edit.